# A partition tolerant relational database

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, scalability

I'm looking for a database that achieves the following:

1. fully ACID.
2. relational with joins.
3. has transactions.
4. allows the administrator to specify sharding rules (for example: users from Europe should be located in the european data center).
5. **the toughest requirement:** upon network partition, like two datacenters disconnected from each other, each datacenter should be able to read and write to the nodes in it.
   Basically, I'm willing to sacrifice **partial** availability to partition tolerance. Sadly, most solutions will stall all reads and writes in case of a split-brain. (thus, preferring availability over partition tolerance)

Comment: Do you want a free solution, or would you use something proprietary? If the latter, you could contact Oracle (etc) sales and see if they can offer anything. I imagine their answer would be "yes, of course!", so you'd have to apply some critical judgment to their answer!

Comment: I'm willing to consider a proprietary solution. I will explore Oracle. thanks!